# use server.transfer and achieve consistent url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 page in my application:

First is:"A.aspx" and Second is:"B.aspx"

A.aspx has one button with event as below:

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
HttpContext.Current.Items["Name"] = "University";

Server.Transfer("B.aspx");

        }
```

In B.aspx :it just writes session data from A.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

Response.Write(Context.Items["Name"].ToString());alues 

        }
```

The issue is when it redirects to "B.aspx" and since i have used server.transfer
the content of "b.aspx" is shown with url as "A.aspx" in address bar which is inconsistent for users.

I want consistent url,means along with content of "B.aspx" ,url should also reflect as "B.aspx".
I tried using Response.Redirect but HttpContext does not work with Response.Redirect as context is getting lost while traversing.
Since i have to implement it in a banking application,So i cannot use querystring ,sessions instead of HttpContext.

So,is there is way to use Response.Redirect with HttpContext or can i manipulate url on page load of B.aspx so as to achieve consistent URL.
Or there is any other way to achieve this.